# Terminal not showing the output of the python file in swarm cron job

Tags: python-3.x, docker, cron, docker-swarm, swarm

I've been using swarm cron job recently and I had faced a problem
the problem is I can't use that to schedule a python file in the root directory
My task is to run a script in a scheduled time with docker swarm
any idea to solve this problem or suggest me another library to use
thanks :)
btw it is my screen shot of swarm cron job :
[image]

and this is my task file in yml format:

```
version: "3.2"

services:   test:
    image: busybox
    command: python3 -u file.py
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 0
      labels:
        - "swarm.cronjob.enable=true"
        - "swarm.cronjob.schedule=CRON_TZ=Asia/Tokyo * * * * *"
        - "swarm.cronjob.skip-running=false"
      restart_policy:
        condition: none
```